# If a box is carried 2 flights of stairs to an attic, is more work done than opposed to go straight up with a ladder?

Tags: forces, energy, kinematics, work

The box has the same weight. I think that the stairs does more work because it travels a further distance as it is a less direct path opposed to going straight up.

Comment: What matters is the _dot product_ of force times distance. The forces in the problem (gravity and the force holding the box up) point vertically. The dot product of perpendicular vectors is zero. Therefore, any distance traveled perpendicular to the force (in this case, any horizontal distance) does not contribute to the work.

Answer (score 2):

If the box is raised a height $h$ the work done on the box is $mgh$ and does not depend on the path taken to raise the weight.  Any horizontal movement does no work on the box, since it is perpendicular to the force of gravity. You will certainly feel like you do more work if you take the longer path that includes horizontal movement, but that’s because your physical effort does not entirely go into the work done on the box.  For example, if you were standing still holding the box the physical effort will expend calories, yet you would not be performing any work on the box.

Hope this helps